# Installing Pillow and PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have [Ubuntu 12.04](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_.28Precise_Pangolin.29) (Precise Pangolin) installed and some package installed, PIL. Now I want to use Pillow, but that cannot be installed at the same time as PIL.

I looked at virtualenv, but there are other packages I don't want to have to install.

Is there another way to set this up without the clash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should install Pillow from the Git clone with (choose `/opt/pillow` as you want):

```
python setup.py install --prefix /opt/pillow
```

And then it include in your code,

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/opt/pillow")
```

before doing the import of Pillow with

```
from PIL import Image
```

This will search the `/opt/pillow` directory first and anything without that insert will never see Pillow.

Answer (score 0):

I set up a fork of Pillow that properly masquerades its package name arbitrarily, when built with the environment variable `PILLOW_NAME` set (e.g. `PILLOW_NAME=PIL`). So you can install Pillow under the PIL package name like this:

```
$ PILLOW_NAME=PIL pip install -U https://github.com/fish2000/Pillow/archive/master.zip
```

... If you wish, you can check the custom package-name installation like so:

```
$ pip freeze | grep -i pil
[...]
PIL==2.3.0
$ python -c 'from PIL import Image' && echo "PIL installed OK"
PIL installed OK
```

If you have this Pillow fork installed under the name “PIL” you’ll be able to install packages that call for PIL as a requirement. Bear in mind: this will not help you if those packages rely on old PIL-specific behavior (e.g. `import Image` and friends) – but it will get you past the name issue when installing packages that specifically require PIL.