# can't import from Pillow package

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I can't use Pillow modules and I'm not sure why.

I'm using a software that includes within it python (2.7) scripter. So I had to install Pillow package manually - just copied the folder into one of the paths that appear in sys.path. Now the paths are:

```
mySoftware\Python27\Pillow
```

and what I was trying to do is:

```
from Pillow.PIL import Image
```

so, it finds Image.py, but in it, it doesn't know PIL:

```
>>> from PIL import VERSION, PILLOW_VERSION, _plugins
ImportError: No module named PIL
>>> from Pillow.PIL import Image
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Sim4Life_v2.2.2.904\Python27\Pillow\PIL\Image.py", line 29, in <module>
```

(Pillow didn't have a `__init__.py` file. not sure if it should have.)

How can I have it find PIL?

Comment: I tried to fix the formatting, but it would be better you reproduce a full transcript of the errors in the question

Comment: Why did you install it manually instead of using pip?

Comment: Pillow needs to be importable with just `from PIL import Image` because Pillow needs to be able to import modules from within itself, maybe see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017319/installing-pillow-and-pil about how to properly install Pillow with custom folder.

Comment: thank you all for you help. Rob, I wanted to do minial extra modules installations. so , finally I did do normal installation, instead of pip, I used easy_install.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use python in different place, than in the main installation folder, you should use `virtualenv`, not manual copy.
If you want to do it your way, try to add path to libs you copied to `sys.path` like this

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('path/to/copied/libs'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but It didn't work. finally I did do normal installation,  I used easy_install.